# When will be the next major update for wordpress?

Tags: upgrade

My client isn't a great fan of updates so I want to assure him that the next major upgrade will be at least 3-4 months down the line. I just upgraded his blog to 3.1 - (YAY!)

Would anyone concur with this or is this just wishful thinking on my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also wish to inform your client that the reason for updates is they include security fixes and patches that will only make their site better. Not running updates can have a very negative impact on their site.

Comment: yeah I have told him that but he is used to desktop computing software which comes with a one time payment.

What I need to show him is what happens when people don't upgrade their web applications - the risks - maybe a case-study perhaps? if you know one, please share it with me.

Comment: Updates aren't obligatory, although they may be strongly advised. If he doesn't want the update, he doesn't have to update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the next a major release (3.2) will take at least 3-4 months.

Besides that, there might be a minor release (3.1.1) soon.